# Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker cannot be started

Tags: service-worker

Everything was working fine with my Service Worker project, but suddenly I am seeing the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker cannot be started
```

This is being reported as on index.html:1 although I am registering the SW in a file called sw.js.

I couldn't find anything on Google - any guidance on what causes this error to occur?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So it turns out this just indicates there is a JS error in the Service Worker code itself, so the registration couldn't complete.

Load chrome://serviceworker-internals/ and check 'Open DevTools window and pause JavaScript execution on Service Worker startup for debugging.'

The inspector will then pop up when you refresh the page, allowing you to see the error in the Service Worker.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which Chrome version/channel were you using?

Comment: I was using Canary 43 (it's updated since so afraid I can't give the exact version)

Comment: Thanks. Our work on bringing SW and Page debugging within the same devtools window should help make that more obvious.

Comment: i was getting a error like window is not defined in firebase-app.js  file but when i gone to chrome://serviceworker-internals/  clicking on unregister and then register solved my problem. So why did i was getting that error ?Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there an equivalent solution for Firefox?

Comment: I got this error on Chrome 60 (Linux). But it only happens intermittently.

Comment: This solution should work for any chromium based browser.