# Failed to register service-worker TypeError - Expo Error

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, service-worker

I have recently encountered the following error when I `npm run start` my expo app;

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on
> 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at
> 'http://localhost:19006/service-worker.js' failed to load.
> at http://localhost:19006/expo-service-worker.js:93:6
>
> The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

This error has never occurred until of late, in which I pulled down the app source code onto a new machine, so I have a incline that this could be the issue.

When I used to Service Worker debugger using Chrome Dev Tools, the error flags up on the last line of the code in `expo-service-worker.js` (see screenshot)

[image: service-worker-error]

I have literally done nothing different, I have seen other solutions stating I should modify some of the service-worker registration code, but this sits uncomfortable with me being as this is an automatic process when running the app.

The app *boots-up* fine, but it has trouble connecting to the external api linked to the app, because the service worker is not being registered.

One my other machine, the app launches, registers a service worker and connects to the api fine, just not on the machine currently.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Very much similar to your example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921937/failed-to-register-a-serviceworker-serviceworker-cannot-be-started

Answer (score 0):

A service worker importScripts() script must be served with a valid javascript content-type header.  See:

https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#dfn-bad-import-script-response

In this case you are getting a content-type of `text/html`.  One common way this can happen is if the server returns a 404 for the resource URL passed to importScripts.